# My printf statement is getting printed on 2 lines one below the other as the output of my program is multiline, but I want it to print just once

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

```
    #!/bin/bash
for n in 1 2;
    do var=$(bc -l <<< 'scale=100; 4*a(1)')
    my_time=$( (time bc -l <<< 'scale=100; 4*a(1)') 2>&1 >/dev/null)
    echo $var
    echo $my_time       
    printf "Value of PI is :%s\n" $var
    printf "Time calculated is :%s\n" $my_time
done
```

Output:

```
real 0m0.005s user 0m0.004s sys 0m0.000s
Value of PI is :3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307\
Value of PI is :8164062862089986280348253421170676
Time calculated is :real
Time calculated is :0m0.005s
Time calculated is :user
Time calculated is :0m0.004s
Time calculated is :sys
Time calculated is :0m0.000s
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307\ 8164062862089986280348253421170676
real 0m0.004s user 0m0.000s sys 0m0.000s
Value of PI is :3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307\
Value of PI is :8164062862089986280348253421170676
Time calculated is :real
Time calculated is :0m0.004s
Time calculated is :user
Time calculated is :0m0.000s
Time calculated is :sys
Time calculated is :0m0.000s
```

As you can see here the statements "Value of PI is" and "Time calculated is" are displayed on each line. Please help!

Comment: Check your script with https://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 0):

Please, put double quotes around `$var` and `$my_time`, really usefull when variables contain line feed (LF aka `\n`).

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for n in 1 2; do
    var=$(bc -l <<< 'scale=100; 4*a(1)')
    my_time=$( (time bc -l <<< 'scale=100; 4*a(1)') 2>&1 >/dev/null)
    echo $var
    echo $my_time       
    printf "Value of PI is :%s\n" "$var"
    printf "Time calculated is :%s\n" "$my_time"
done
```

If you want a `bc` result on only one line, add `BC_LINE_LENGTH=0`  before:

```
BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc -l <<< 'scale=100; 4*a(1)'
```

(tested with bc 1.07.1)